# How to chain rewrites in Nginx?

Tags: apache-2.2, nginx, rewrite, .htaccess

I'm new to nginx's rewrite engine. I'm trying to convert my old htaccess file over to nginx's format but I'm running into some trouble.

```
# ------------------------------------------------------ #
# This redirects index.php to /                          #
# ------------------------------------------------------ #

    RewriteCond %{THE_REQUEST} ^[A-Z]+\ /(index|index\.php)\ HTTP/
    RewriteRule ^(index|index\.php)$ http://domain.com/ [R=301,L] 

# ------------------------------------------------------ #
# This rewrites 'directories' to their PHP files,        #
# fixes trailing-slash issues, and redirects .php        #
# to 'directory' to avoid duplicate content.             #
# ------------------------------------------------------ #

    RewriteCond %{DOCUMENT_ROOT}/$1.php -f
    RewriteRule ^(.*)$ $1.php [L]

    RewriteCond %{DOCUMENT_ROOT}/$1.php -f
    RewriteRule ^(.*)/$ http://twitstamp.com/$1 [R=301,L]

    RewriteCond %{THE_REQUEST} ^[A-Z]+\ /[^.]+\.php\ HTTP/
    RewriteCond %{DOCUMENT_ROOT}/$1.php -f
    RewriteRule ^([^.]+)\.php$ http://twitstamp.com/$1 [R=301,L]

# ------------------------------------------------------ #
# If it wasn't redirected previously and is not          #
# a file on the server, rewrite to image                 #
# ------------------------------------------------------ #

    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d 
    RewriteRule ^([a-z0-9_\-@#\ "'\+]+)/?([a-z0-9_\-]+)?(\.png|/)?$ generation/image.php?user=${escapemap:$1}&template=${escapemap:$2} [NC,L]
```

That's my htaccess file. Now here's what I've got so far...

```
# ------------------------------------------------------ #
# This redirects index.php to /                          #
# ------------------------------------------------------ #
if ($request_uri ~* "^/index.php\??$") {
    rewrite ^.*$ http://$host? permanent;
}


# ------------------------------------------------------ #
# This rewrites 'directories' to their PHP files,        #
# fixes trailing-slash issues, and redirects .php        #
# to 'directory' to avoid duplicate content.             #
# ------------------------------------------------------ #
if (!-e $request_filename) {
    rewrite ^(.*)$ $1.php;
    last;
}


# ------------------------------------------------------ #
# If it wasn't redirected previously and is not          #
# a file on the server, rewrite to image                 #
# ------------------------------------------------------ #

if (!-e $request_filename) {
    rewrite ^([a-z0-9_\-@#\ "'\+]+)/?([a-z0-9_\-]+)?(\.png|/)?$ generation/image.php?user=$1&template=$2;
    break;
}
```

The index.php redirect works fine, as does the "directory" name -> php file redirect. However, I can't figure out how to do several things: Implement the trailing-slash fix, and externally redirecting .php files so that I don't have any duplicate files. I want all pages to look clean, like /help, /about, etc. The real pages on the server are /about.php format. Also, I can't get the rewrite rule for the images working. I want anything that's not a real file or directory (-e flag) and not a rewritable file (like /about) to redirect to generation/etc...

Answer (score 1):

You're going about it wrong. Nginx loves location blocks, for instance to redirect /index.php to / you'd do.

```
location = /index.php {
    rewrite ^ http://domain.com/$args permanent;
}
```

You'll also want to look into try_files. In general, if you're using an if in Nginx then chances are you're doing it wrong.

I recommend reading this for a basic introduction on how Nginx uses server blocks and location blocks: http://blog.martinfjordvald.com/2010/07/nginx-primer/